# Extjs Hidden Iframe requests are missing OWASP CSRF token

Tags: java, iframe, extjs, csrf, owasp

Recently we have implemented `OWASP CSRF` security token concept to handle `CSRF` attacks. I used below links as reference to implement

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CSRFGuard_Project

https://github.com/aramrami/OWASP-CSRFGuard

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>csrfguard</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.590</version>
</dependency>
```

I made all the mandatory changes to my project. Now i could able to see `OWASP_CSRFTOKEN` as part of request headers.

**Problem:**

In my project we are using `Extjs 4`. after implementing the change all ajax calls are successfully carrying `OWASP_CSRFTOKEN` token.

We do have one `Hidden Iframe` being used to download some excel files from server. when i inspect this request it's not carrying `OWASP_CSRFTOKEN` token and in server logs i can see the below message.

**Logs:**

```
Nov 21, 2017 2:53:47 PM org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger log
WARNING: potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, 
         ip:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, method:%request_method%, uri:/aaa/template/onDemandTemplate.action, 
         error:required token is missing from the request)
```

**Iframe code:**

```
var body = Ext.getBody(),
frame = body.createChild({
        tag:'iframe',
        cls:'x-hidden',
        id:'hiddenform-iframe',
        name:'iframe'
        }),
form = body.createChild({
        tag:'form',
        cls:'x-hidden',
        id:'hiddenform-form',
        action: url,
        method: POST,
        target:'iframe'
        });
var hiddenItem = document.createElement('input');
        Ext.fly(hiddenItem).set({
            type: 'hidden',
            value: Ext.encode(params),
            name: 'reportingParams'
           });
form.appendChild(hiddenItem);
form.dom.submit();
```

*Does Hidden Iframes internally use ajax or not ?*

*How can i inject CSRF token manually in Iframe reqeusts?*

If any one have better approach/option to handle this situation. please share your ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. No Iframes do not use ajax. However Iframe like functionality can be achieved by ajax.
2. If you are going to use Iframes then add a 2nd hidden input for CSRF token.

   **Code**:

```
        var csrf= document.createElement('input');
        Ext.fly(hiddenItem).set({
            type: 'hidden',
            value: getCsrf,// method to get csrf token from the cookie
            name: 'csrf'
           });
        form.appendChild(csrf);
```

3. Since you are using Extjs, you are assuming that the client browser is java script enabled, so avoid Iframes and use ajax to download the Excel files.